# How do I make NotebookEvaluate work inside Button?

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages, dialog-window

The following creates a button to select a notebook to run. When the button is pressed it seems that Mathematica finds the notebook but cannot evaluate it. The following error occurs

> Could not process unknown packet "1"

```
Button["run file 1", 
     NotebookEvaluate[
      "/../file1.nb"]]
```

This occurs under Mathematica 8 on all platforms.

Any help greatly appreciated,
Christina

Comment: Does using `Button[..., Method->"Queued"]` help?

Comment: Please evaluate this (and press the button) and report the result:  `Button["run file 1", 
    TracePrint @ NotebookEvaluate[
      "/../file1.nb"]]
`

Comment: Also, please try a fully qualified path name, e.g. `"C:/User/Notebooks/file1.nb"` or whatever.

Comment: `Button[..., Method->"Queued"]` worked. Many thanks celtschk and @Mr.Wizard

Comment: @celtschk please post that as an answer, or I shall.  Christina, glad you've got it working!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make it work, use

```
Button["run file 1", NotebookEvaluate["/../file1.nb"], Method->"Queued"]
```

Answer (score 4):

In the comments celtschk suggested `Button[..., Method -> "Queued"]` and Christina confirmed it as a solution.

Comment: @Christina does `Button["run 1", NotebookEvaluate["/../file1.nb"]]` also work by itself?

Comment: Great question @Mr.Wizard. It doesn't, I get the same error, so my question should actually be "How do I make NotebookEvaluate work inside Button?" I can't believe I didn't test that.