# Evaluate Initialization Cells of another notebook

Tags: front-end, initialization

Although there may be better ways to get data and definitions from another notebook (packages, read/write dumps, ...), sometimes it is convenient to just evaluate the initialization cells from another notebook to re-use the data and definitions.

Normally I would open this notebook and manually `Evaluate Initialization Cells`, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this automatically, i.e. with some code.

**Question: is there a way to evaluate the Initialization Cells of a certain notebook by filename?**

Related questions:

- [Evaluation of Notebook chosen by FileNameSetter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9375/evaluation-of-notebook-chosen-by-filenamesetter)
- [How to select all initialization cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/how-to-select-all-initialization-cells)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it is more convenient to use NotebookEvaluate. We can do

```
NotebookEvaluate[filename, EvaluationElements-> "InitializationCell"]
```

Confusing here may be that this has the same result as

```
NotebookEvaluate[filename, EvaluationElements -> Automatic]
```

Even though if we simply do

```
NotebookEvaluate[filename]
```

all the cells get evaluated.

Comment: I did not know `NoteBookEvaluate` and you are right: that's much sleeker than my solution. Thanks!

Comment: @A.Goossens Well, I'm glad you asked :). With all the Notebook functions it can be hard to find the right one.

Comment: @Jacob +1. Are you sure `NotebookEvaluate` does not use the FrontEnd in background?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ah yes, maybe there was a bit of bluff there. I will use it from shell interface to make sure

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov ah, it does use the front end! Sorry for the misdirection, I will edit.

Answer (score 8):

I'm questioning AND answering this because I was looking for a feature like this for a while and now stumbled across `FrontEndToken["EvaluateInitialization"]` which does exactly what I wanted.

Here is the code to make it work:

```
filename = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
nb = NotebookOpen[filename];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "EvaluateInitialization"]];
NotebookClose[nb]
```

Feel free to add improvements or submit an alternative solution.

Hope you like and use this feature as much as I do!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you achieve with the above code?