# What is the difference between NotebookEvaluate and FrontEndToken

Tags: front-end, notebooks, initialization

I am wondering what exactly are the differences in using

`NotebookEvaluate[filename]` **vs** `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "EvaluateInitialization"]]`;

to evaluate cells in a given notebook.

In particular, I am referring to the discussion: [Evaluate Initialization Cells of another notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26123/evaluate-initialization-cells-of-another-notebook/26124#26124). Given my new status here, I couldn't see how I could continue with that conversation directly, so I decided to post a new queston.

The comments in the referenced question proposed these two solutions to the problem:

- method 1.

  ```
  filename = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
  NotebookEvaluate[filename, EvaluationElements -> "InitializationCell"]
  ```
- method 2.

  ```
  filename = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
  nb = NotebookOpen[filename];
  FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "EvaluateInitialization"]];
  NotebookClose[nb]
  ```

I am trying to solve the same problem. Taken at face value, it seems both approaches are valid. Are there any subtleties that make one preferred to the other, issues of scope/context, etc.?

Comment: Have you tried consulting the documentation centre ?

Comment: Yes, and from that documentation I see no difference. i.e. two different ways to achieve the same end result. I was confused by the discussion between @AlexeyPopkov and Jacob which I took to suggest there is a difference between the two methods with regards to what happens in the FrontEnd vs kernel.

Comment: `NotebookEvaluate` returns the last expression evaluated. Also, to make them more comparable you may have to add `NotebookOpen[..., Visible->False]`

Comment: I suppose this may be the same case: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120963/5478, but I don't have time to try it now.