# Global context seems to be shared between kernels when using Clear?

Tags: version-10, kernel, contexts, clear

I am trying to understand the following behaviour, and determine if it's a bug in *Mathematica* 10. I am using *Mathematica* 10.3, and can't reproduce this behaviour under *Mathematica* 9. The test outlined below shows that evaluating `` Clear["Global`*"] `` under one kernel clears the `Global` context in another kernel, which I don't understand - I thought each kernel had it's own `Global` context.

To demonstrate, I have created a simple notebook called `clear.nb` containing:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

and nothing else. I have also created two new kernels called Test1 and Test2.

Now in another notebook I have the following:

```
f = 99.0

nb = NotebookOpen["/path/to/clear.nb"]

SetOptions[nb, Evaluator -> "Test1"]

NotebookEvaluate[nb]
```

Evaluating this notebook under kernel `Test2`, I find that immediately after the `NotebookEvaluate[nb]` both `nb` and `f` are no longer defined. In other words the `` Clear["Global`*"] `` which has been evaluated by kernel `Test1` has cleared the `Global` context of kernel `Test2`.

This is not what I expected at all, and now how it worked in *Mathematica* 9, where the `Global` context of kernel `Test2` is unaffected.

Is this a bug in *Mathematica* 10, or a bug in my understanding/expectation?

Comment: This is a great question and I am sorry to see that it has been widely ignored up until now!

Answer (score 9):

If you look at the definition of NotebookEvaluate, by means of

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[NotebookEvaluate]
```

you see that the design is strange: always `$ParentLink` is set to `First@$FrontEnd`, and the designer obviously never thought about your use case.

However, it is easy to achieve what you want, just define e.g.

```
nbEval[nb_NotebookObject] := (SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook]; 
   SelectionEvaluate[nb]);
```

and now use `nbEval` instead of `NotebookEvaluate` and all is good.

Comment: Can you contrast the code from version 9?  It might be telling if there is a clear design change regarding the evaluation.

Comment: Same situation with version 9. At least on Windows. Did not check other operating systems.

Comment: Thank you.  So at least *on Windows* this statement is incorrect?: "*This is not what I expected at all, and now how it worked in Mathematica 9, where the Global context of kernel Test2 is unaffected.*"

Comment: @Mr.Wizard With version 8.0.4 I get the same behavior as with version 10.4.1 on Win7 x64 (both with `InsertResults -> True` and without it): the `"clear.nb"` Notebook is evaluated using the Kernel `"Test2"` and its ``"Global`"`` context is cleared. So the `Evaluator` option of `"clear.nb"` is ignored.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was working on Linux, rather than Windows in case that matters (I doubt it does).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Rolf's workaround.

This is expected and works the same in V9 and V10.

`NotebookEvaluate` / Details & Options:

> By default, `NotebookEvaluate` evaluates the cells of a notebook **in the same way that `Get` evaluates the lines of a package file. Messages, print output, and other side effects will be placed as output to the cell that called `NotebookEvaluate` rather than the specified notebook**. Existing output cells in the notebook will not be updated or deleted.

So you are not running the `clear.nb`, `NotebookEvaluate` reads it and evaluates it itself in the parent kernel.

---

Though one may get confused because the next bullet point says:

> `NotebookEvaluate[notebook,InsertResults->True]` evaluates the notebook as if all cells had been evaluated with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Messages, print output, and other side effects are placed in the notebook along with outputs.

and this is really misleading, outputs are inserted but the first sentence should be changed.

WRI Support agrees

> CASE:3673620
>
> [...] I have filed a suggestion with the appropriate development team requesting we review the documentation on `NotebookEvaluate`. As particularly outlined in the StackExchange thread, there is room for confusion here with more advanced uses. [...]

Comment: "and this is really misleading, outputs are inserted but the first sentence should be changed." -- I read that too, and I wondered if it actually *was* supposed to work that way but someone made a mistake?  As usual when the documentation and implementation disagree we are left guessing as to which is "correct."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Documentation is usually correct from a perspective of a beginner who doesn't care/know context/kernels/links etc. When you try to develop something complex then those reckless sentences have major implications. Sometimes it is a matter of few tests and sometimes you waste two days on debugging and discussions here.

Comment: I would have thought that if you kept reading, it would have been clarified by a later bullet point..."The cells of the notebook are evaluated in a dialog subsession."  But I'll tweak it.