# Question on Total and Mean

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose a single data set contains entries with different dimensions,

```
{RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {2, 2}], RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {3, 3}]}
```

and one wants to obtain the Mean value of 10 such data sets:

```
dat=Table[{RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {2, 2}], RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {3, 3}]}, 10];
```

My question is, why does `Mean[dat]` not work whereas `Total[dat]/10` does work?

Comment: I'm surprised that `Total[]` actually worked...

Comment: @J.M. Why? Rows are all same structure...

Comment: @ciao, it's still a ragged array, after all. But I am glad it does work.

Comment: Help says that `Mean[list] is equivalent to Total[list]/Length[list]` so arguably this is a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The observed behavior appears to caused by `Mean` having different requirements than `Total`. Or you might say it is being fussier.

The **Details and Options** section of the *Documentation Center* article on [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) says

> For a 2D array or matrix, Total[list] totals for each column

That means `Total[list]` effectively transposes `data`, so a truly equivalent application of `Mean` would be

```
SeedRandom[42]; 
data = Table[{RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {2, 2}], RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {3, 3}]}, 10];
Mean /@ Transpose[data]
```

> ```
> {{{-0.0841252, 0.30287}, {0.188753, 0.258856}}, 
>  {{-0.219886, 0.0948545, 0.310493}, {-0.127705, 0.0855042, 0.508691}, 
>   {0.113957, 0.328553, 0.405479}}}
> ```

which is what

```
Total[data]/Length[data]
```

gives.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be one of those cases where the documentation tries to illustrate with a simple analogy which unfortunately is only superficially true.

I am going to [quote Kuba directly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110970/global-context-seems-to-be-shared-between-kernels-when-using-clear/120963#comment327825_120963) as I think he expressed this quite well:

> Documentation is usually correct from a perspective of a beginner who doesn't care/know context/kernels/links etc. When you try to develop something complex then those reckless sentences have major implications. Sometimes it is a matter of few tests and sometimes you waste two days on debugging and discussions here.

And [quoting myself](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71557/121):

> Quite often the documentation is not complete in describing the behavior of Mathematica functions. In my opinion a user has to accept in vivo behavior as at least co-authoritative with the documentation. I know this causes consternation for those who want a rigorous language definition but as far as I know from the beginning we have never been provided with one.

The error message itself appears to both explain the problem and clearly indicate that `Mean` was not intended to work this way.  I far simpler example may be used to provoke it:

```
dat = {{{1, 2}, {3}}, {{4, 5}, {6}}};

Mean[dat]
```

> Mean::rectt: Rectangular array expected at position 1 in Mean[{{{1,2},{3}},{{4,5},{6}}}]. >>

`Total` again works as desired:

```
Total[dat]/Length[dat]
```

> ```
> {{5/2, 7/2}, {9/2}}
> ```

`Mean` *expects a rectangular array* as the message indicates.  So, as I see m_goldberg just beat me to posting, we need to make sure that what is passed to `Mean` *is* a rectangular array, and we can do that by separating our `dat`:

```
Mean @ dat[[All, 1]]
Mean @ dat[[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> {5/2, 7/2}
>
> {9/2}
> ```

Or more elegantly as m_goldberg wrote, using `Transpose`:

```
Mean /@ (dat\[Transpose])
```

> ```
> {{5/2, 7/2}, {9/2}}
> ```