# NotebookEvaluate breaks notebook's context

Tags: bugs, front-end, evaluation, contexts, system

**Bug introduced in 10.4.1 or earlier and persists through 12.0**

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3813108] was created
>
> [...] I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided [...]

---

Here is an example of a notebook with local context:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{
  ExpressionCell[Defer @ CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext], "Input"],
  ExpressionCell[Defer @ $Context, "Input"]
 },
 CellContext -> Notebook
]
```

Let's `NotebookEvaluate` it twice:

```
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True]
```

> ```
> "Notebook$$35$971589`"
> ```

```
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True]
```

> ```
> "Global`"
> ```

We can see that the first evaluation was done with respect to the local context but left the notebook broken. It now works with `` Global` ``  context despite `CellContext->Notebook`.

According to [NotebookEvaluate / Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookEvaluate.html) one should expect `"Notebook$$35$971589`"` each time. Ok, one could arguee here but everyone will probably agree that the result should at least be consistent each time.

**Is this a bug or have I missed something?**

---

Related:

- [`NotebookEvaluate` and notebook's `Evaluator`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110970/5478)
- [How does the Kernel know the $Context in a localized notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120621/5478)

---

> [...] A possible fix to this had been suggested in the previous email. [...]

Which is to use `CellContext->Notebook` as an explicit option for each cell.

Answer (score 5):

With

```
$Version
(* 11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016) *)
```

The result depends on the context of the first notebook.  If it is "Global`", I obtain the result in the question.  However, if the context is set by "Evaluation>Notebook's Default Context>Unique to this Notebook", the second notebook's context is unchanged for multiple calls to

```
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True]
```

I also ran the first notebook with the context set to "Anything`". The behavior was like that in the question but with the second call to

```
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True]
```

returning "Anything`" as the context of the second notebook.

I believe that this is a bug.