# NotebookEvaluate within cell with CellContext->Notebook

Tags: front-end, contexts, system, automation

I've encountered the following issue with `NotebookEvaluate` (note the grouping into 3 distinct cells):

```
(* Cell 1 *)
$Context
(* "Global`" *)

(* Cell 2 *)
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellContext -> Notebook]
nb3 = NotebookCreate[];
NotebookEvaluate[nb3, InsertResults -> True];
$Context
(* "Notebook$$16$795021`" *)

(* Cell 3 *)
$Context
(* "Notebook$$16$795021`" *)
```

As can be seen, the `NotebookEvaluate` cell breaks the `$Context` of the original notebook.

*Am I missing something? Or is this simply a bug? And most importantly, what's the easiest way to fix this?*

I could wrap the whole thing inside `Block[{$Context=$Context},...]` but that doesn't seem right - It doesn't fix the issue properly, as I cannot wrap the `Block` directly around the `NotebookEvaluate`, as the context is already wrong there, it just fixes the symptomes later

## Related

- [NotebookEvaluate breaks notebook's context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135025/notebookevaluate-breaks-notebooks-context) - As opposed to there, my issue is that the context on the caller site is messed up
- [How does the Kernel know the $Context in a localized notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/how-does-the-kernel-know-the-context-in-a-localized-notebook) - This might have something to do with my issue in the sense that the front-end forgets to set the proper context