# Unexpected symbol::shdw warning during NotebookEvaluate

Tags: scoping, symbols, automation

Consider the following code:

```
x = 1;

nb = NotebookPut@Notebook[
    {
     Cell[
      BoxData@ToBoxes@Defer@{$Context, x = 2},
      "Input",
      CellContext -> Notebook
      ]
     }
    ];

NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True];
```

This code first creates `` Global`x ``, then it creates a notebook with a cell with `CellContext->Notebook`. Evaluating the notebook using `NotebookEvaluate` creates the symbol `` Notebook$$…`x ``, everything works as expected.

But now, let's replace the last line with the following:

```
Block[{$ContextPath = $ContextPath},
 NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True];
 ]
```

Rerunning the code (including the creation of the notebook), now issues a shadowing warning for `x`.

Why is this happening? This seems to be a rather strange effect of `Block`...

Comment: `Block` with `$ContextPath` causes all sorts of weird shadowing messages where they shouldn't be. I've reported a few cases of this as bugs but my guess is WRI doesn't care about such a minor/cosmetic one when they've got so many other bugs to quash.

Comment: `NotebookEvaluate` does not cope well with `CellContext->Notebook`: [135025](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135025/5478)

Comment: Also the interpretation of docs "The cells of the notebook are evaluated in a dialog subsession." can imply that it is strange it didn't happen with the first one. Don't know where a 'dialog subsession' is defined though.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks, good to know I'm not going crazy. Are you aware of any other symbols that cause similar problems when used with block?

Comment: @LukasLang none that are unexpected. I think Mathematica just has a botched implementation of its `$ContextPath` stack creation mechanism or like the way it reads that stack or something.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, I'm aware of those problems - but I thought I "fixed" most of them by now (i.e. employed ugly workarounds), until I encountered this one. Unfortunately, I really need `NotebookEvalute` so I'll have to live with all its quirks...Regarding the dialog subsession: why would you expect the first example to also produce a warning? In terms of documentation, there is a least some information in the doc page of `Dialog` and the "Dialogs" tutorial, but nothing too specific.

Comment: @LukasLang is `CellContext->Notebook` in context of `NotebookEvaluate` working like `Begin` or `BeginPackage`? My point was that there are many not really precisely defined actions so who knows what really should happen. But yes, it is clearly unexpected.