# Use of standard form in .wl package

Tags: syntax, packages, boxes

In a .wl package, i use the package notation but it is presented as inputform and it is consequently not very easy to read.

```
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubsuperscriptBox["P", "b1_", "b2_"]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"MatPassage", "[", RowBox[{"b1_", ",", "b2_"}], "]"}]]]
```

Is it possible to use the standard form presentation in a .wl package and if yes, how can i transform the lines in inputform in standard form?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Ctrl+a and then Ctrl+Shift+N?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+N works well indeed. But, the altercations that I can conduct with Ctrl+Shift+N are not preserved after having saved my .wl package. How can I preserve this formatting ?

Comment: impossible in .wl

Comment: it is a pity for visualizing the lines that use my notation package

Comment: Lots of these characters are built into Mathematica so a standard text editor won't have them. You can open and edit .m and .wl in Mathematica though.

Comment: I had trouble if my notation was inside the `BeginPackage[...]` and `EndPackage[]` but if it was after the `EndPackage[]` (but still inside my .wl) it worked correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can't / it is not worth using `` Notation` `` package with .m/.wl files.

You can develop your package in a .nb file if you are going to only work with the FrontEnd. See `NotebookEvaluate` and be aware of subtle issues: [Global context seems to be shared between kernels when using Clear?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110970/5478)

Mathematica tries to save code from .m/.wl files as input text which excludes usage of 2D box expressions Notation package works with. If specific box structure can't be converted to input form it will be kept verbatim but there is no control over what gets translated and what not. You'd have to have access to how MMA parses and saves packages. Not possible / too cumbersome.

And packages were not meant for this anyway, they are supposed to contain input form which can be edited/read in external editors.

Related question: [Symbolize Does Not Work in `.m` Files or What?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147293/5478)